# Java guessing number with sockets server-client

Tags: java, sockets, numbers

server socket is created and waits for a client to connect. Once the client connects, it has to guess the number that was generated on the server. If not, will ask the number continuously.

SERVER:

```
    package pruebas;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int num_aleatorio = generarNumAleatorio(); //genera un número aleatorio
        int num_usuario=0;
        int intentos=0;
        boolean adivinado = false;

        System.out.println("Generated number: " + num_aleatorio);

        ServerSocket server_socket = null; //server_socket de tipo sevidor
        Socket client_socket = null; //server_socket tipo cliente

        System.out.println("Server OK...\nWaiting players...");

        try {

            server_socket = new ServerSocket(1111); //nuevo socket servidor con puerto 1111
            client_socket = server_socket.accept(); //El servidor acepta el socket cliente     
            System.out.println("El cliente se ha conectado");

            //Declaramos los emisores/receptores
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()));

            while(true)
            {
                 if(!adivinado){
                     out.writeBoolean(false);
                     num_usuario = in.readInt(); //recoger num del usuario

                     if(num_usuario == num_aleatorio){
                         adivinado = true; 
                         out.writeBoolean(true);
                      } 
                    else if(num_usuario > num_aleatorio) out.writeUTF("El número es menor que " + num_usuario);
                    else if(num_usuario < num_aleatorio) out.writeUTF("El número es mayor que " + num_usuario);
                    intentos++;
                 }
                 else if(adivinado) out.writeUTF("Has acertado! Con un total de " + intentos + " intentos.");
                 else
                 {
                     server_socket.close();
                     client_socket.close();
                 }
            }           
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port 1111 or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static int generarNumAleatorio()
    {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 100 +1); //del 0 al 99 (el +1 hace que sea del 1 al 100)
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
    package pruebas;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Adivina el número!");

        int num_usuario=0;
        boolean errores=false;
        boolean adivinado=false;
        Socket client_socket = null;

        try{
            client_socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1111); //se crea un socket

            //Declaramos los emisores/receptores
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()));

           do{

            //PEDIR NUMERO AL USUARIO
            do{
                errores = false;
                try{
                    System.out.print("Introduce un número del 1-99:");
                    num_usuario = teclado.nextInt();
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.print("\n Introduce valores numéricos!\n");
                    errores = true;
                    teclado.nextLine(); //evitar bucle de error
                }
             }while(errores);

             out.writeInt(num_usuario); //enviar num_usuario al server
             out.flush();

             adivinado = in.readBoolean();

             System.out.println(in.readUTF());//mostrar resultado del server

           }while(!adivinado);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host ");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to "+ e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            teclado.close();
            client_socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The program asking for the number, but the program will not return if it is greater or less, why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem with your protocol is that the reader doesn't know what type of data you sent.  I suggest using String only to start with as it would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in the server has many problems in it:

1. You start by sending `false` to the client, even before the client makes a guess
2. Whenever the guess is incorrect, you send a string message followed by a `false` value. The client expects the opposite order.
3. Whenever the guess is correct, the server enters an infinite loop sending the "Has acertado..." text to the client.